# Android chrome custom tabs with auto fill information

Tags: javascript, android, chromium, autofill, chrome-custom-tabs

I want to create application which capable to auofill information using Chrome custom tabs. In chrome custom tabs, can I modify view for Autofill information? Please give me advice for same.

Answer (score 0):

CustomTabs is just Chrome with a customized view. There is no supported way to access Chrome autofill internals from an app.